# how to call a fragment method in an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a dialog method in my fragment, which I want to call from my main activity FAB.

I tried to call it, but got this error;

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.LayoutInflater android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getLayoutInflater()' on a null object reference
```

editProfileDialog() is the dialog method in my fragment that I tried to call in my main activity.

```
public class Edit_fragment extends Fragment {

private EditPresenter mEditPresenter;

public Edit_fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_profile_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    mEditPresenter = new EditPresenter(this);
    mEditPresenter.onCreate();

    return view;
}


public void editProfileDialog(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_profile_dialogue, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(dialoglayout);
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    TextView edit_profile = (TextView)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_me);
    Typeface Sms = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/FTLTLT.TTF");
    edit_profile.setTypeface(Sms);

    TextView new_profile_photo = (TextView)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.addAvatar);
    new_profile_photo.setTypeface(Sms);


    TextView edit_username = (TextView)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.editUsernameBtn);
    edit_username.setTypeface(Sms);

    TextView Change_bio = (TextView)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.statusLayout);
    Change_bio.setTypeface(Sms);

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    new_profile_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            editPhotoDialog();
        }
    });

    edit_username.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    Change_bio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });


    dialog.show();
}

private void editPhotoDialog(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_photo_dialogue, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(dialoglayout);
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    FrameLayout cameraBtn = (FrameLayout)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.cameraBtn);

    FrameLayout galleryBtn = (FrameLayout)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.galleryBtn);

    AppCompatTextView cameraBtnTxt = (AppCompatTextView)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.cameraBtnTxt);
    Typeface Sms = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/FTLTLT.TTF");
    cameraBtnTxt.setTypeface(Sms);


    AppCompatTextView galleryBtnText = (AppCompatTextView)dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.galleryBtnText);
    galleryBtnText.setTypeface(Sms);

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            setCameraBtn();
        }
    });

    galleryBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            setGalleryBtn();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

private void setGalleryBtn() {
    if (PermissionHandler.checkPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        AppHelper.LogCat("Read data permission already granted.");
        new PickerBuilder(getActivity(), PickerBuilder.SELECT_FROM_GALLERY)
                .setOnImageReceivedListener(imageUri -> {
                    Intent data = new Intent();
                    data.setData(imageUri);
                    AppHelper.LogCat("new image SELECT_FROM_GALLERY" + imageUri);
                    mEditPresenter.onActivityResult(this, AppConst.SELECT_PROFILE_PICTURE, RESULT_OK, data);

                })
                .setImageName(getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setImageFolderName(getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setCropScreenColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .withTimeStamp(false)
                .setOnPermissionRefusedListener(() -> {
                    PermissionHandler.requestPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                })
                .start();

    } else {
        AppHelper.LogCat("Please request Read data permission.");
        PermissionHandler.requestPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }

}



private void setCameraBtn() {
    if (PermissionHandler.checkPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        AppHelper.LogCat("camera permission already granted.");
        new PickerBuilder(getActivity(), PickerBuilder.SELECT_FROM_CAMERA)
                .setOnImageReceivedListener(imageUri -> {

                    AppHelper.LogCat("new image SELECT_FROM_CAMERA " + imageUri);
                    Intent data = new Intent();
                    data.setData(imageUri);
                    mEditPresenter.onActivityResult(this, AppConst.SELECT_PROFILE_CAMERA, RESULT_OK, data);

                })
                .setImageName(getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setImageFolderName(getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setCropScreenColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .withTimeStamp(false)
                .setOnPermissionRefusedListener(() -> {
                    PermissionHandler.requestPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                })
                .start();
    } else {
        AppHelper.LogCat("Please request camera  permission.");
        PermissionHandler.requestPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }
}

}
```

On my fab.setOnClickListener() that is in my main_activity. I called editProfileDialog() like this;

```
mEdit_profile_fragment.editProfileDialog();
```

AND THAT ERROR SHOWED UP IN THE LOGCAT.

Comment: where is fab on click event?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your method to this:

```
    public void editProfileDialog(Context context){
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_profile_dialogue, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setView(dialoglayout);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
```

**This is because getActivity() is not available in activity class.**

Comment: I got this:  cannot resolve method 'getLayoutInflater()'

Comment: I got this: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Did you passed properly initialised context in the method ?

Comment: couldn't get your question

Comment: The method requires context as a parameter. Have you initialised your context value before passing to this method ?

Comment: I just did it as you posted it and called the method as mEdit_profile_fragment.editProfileDialog(null); in my main activity

Comment: what you are calling doesn't have context in the method call . Pass the context like Main activity.this and it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, but still crashes at setCameraBtn(); and setGalleryBtn();  in cameraBtn.setOnClickListener and galleryBtn.setOnClickListener. Any solution to that?

Comment: same problem with those method too. getActivity() is used in fragment to get context of the hosting activity. While you are calling it in activity itself so getActivity() doesn't make any sense. Pass the context like the above method.

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_profile_dialogue, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
builder.setCancelable(true);
```

Comment: i got this: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: The getApplicationContext is redundant. You only need getActivity().getSystemService()

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
   Edit_fragment homeFragment = (Edit_fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Edit_fragment.class.getSimpleName());

   if(fragment != null){
                fragment.editProfileDialog();
   }
```

Comment: It couldn't carry any operation

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
```